# If any value of list = x, do this

Tags: python

```
cat = [1, 2, 3]


def any_of_list(LIST):

    if ***any value of LIST*** == 2:

        print('yes')

    else:

        print('no')



any_of_list(cat)
```

OUTPUT = 'yes'

Im not sure how to enter the bold. Please help.

Comment: Please reformat your code

Comment: It's simply `if 2 in LIST:`

Answer (score 1):

The general case would be to use built-in `any` like

```
def any_of_list(LIST):
    if any(x == 2 for x in LIST):
        print('yes')
    ...
```

Another example `if any(i % 3 == 0 for i in LIST):` to find if there is a multiple of 3 in the list

---

But here as you just look for inclusion you can do

```
def any_of_list(LIST):
    if 2 in LIST:
        print('yes')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
if any(x == 2 for x in LIST):
```

Comment: That would just be `if 2 in LIST`

Comment: Code is an error for python2.7 and 3.8, you're probably using numpy ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve that explicitly, do

```py
def any_of_list(l):
    for x in l:
        if x == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

If you want to use the functional programming features of Python, on the other hand,

```
def any_of_list(l):
    return any(map(lambda x: x == 2, l))
```

will do the same. If you want to use this approach, make sure to look up `any`, `map` and `lambda` in the Python Library and Language Reference.

Beware that `any_of_list` is a rather bad name for that function, it is not very descriptive. Go for something like `any_is_two`.

Comment: Wow, didn't think of that.